# subprocess Popen splits arguments with ssh

Tags: python, python-2.6

When I try to exectue a command over ssh with subprocess.Popen arguments that contain a space are split into several arguments. What am I doing wrong? And how can I fix this so that the remote script gets the arguments correctly quoted?

code:

```
#!/usr/bin/python2.6
import sys
import subprocess

print "\n ### Starting test.py ###"
print "sys.argv:", sys.argv

if "--exit" in sys.argv:
    print "Bye..."
    sys.exit(1)

# Create command
full_cmd = ["ssh", "localhost"]
full_cmd.append("/home/moberg/tmp/test.py")
full_cmd.extend(sys.argv[1:])
full_cmd.append("--exit")

print "full_cmd:", full_cmd

prog = subprocess.Popen(full_cmd)
prog.communicate()
sys.exit(prog.returncode)
```

output:

```
./test.py -p --act="hej hej"

 ### Starting test.py ###
sys.argv: ['./test.py', '-p', '--act=hej hej']
full_cmd: ['ssh', 'localhost', '/home/moberg/tmp/test.py', '-p', '--act=hej hej', '--exit']

 ### Starting test.py ###
sys.argv: ['/home/moberg/tmp/test.py', '-p', '--act=hej', 'hej', '--exit']
Bye...
```

Expected ouput is `sys.argv: ['/home/moberg/tmp/test.py', '-p', '--act=hej hej', '--exit']`

**Clarification:** This only happens when I use ssh in the command. Removing "ssh", "localhost" from the cmd and the argument is kept intact; output is what I expect:

```
./test.py -p --act="hej hej"

 ### Starting test.py ###
sys.argv: ['./test.py', '-p', '--act=hej hej']
full_cmd: ['/home/moberg/tmp/test.py', '-p', '--act=hej hej', '--exit']

 ### Starting test.py ###
sys.argv: ['/home/moberg/tmp/test.py', '-p', '--act=hej hej', '--exit']
Bye...
```

Comment: You must write a hight level arguments parser to send `--act="hej hej"` to ssh. I don't see any other way because shell remove quotation marks and there isn't any simple way to recover them if you don't *understand what the arguments means*.

Comment: If I remove the "ssh", "localhost" part the shell knows that this is one argument and does not remove quotes. Why is it different?

Comment: Update your question with that case.

Comment: I cannot understand: if you took a look to `sys.argv` dump you can see that the quotes are already removed.

Comment: When you remove `ssh` if you want simulate the same behavior you need to use `shell=True` parameter in `Popen()`

Comment: The quotes was removed when you enter in `test.py` the first time. If you use `Popen()` without a shell it will pass the arguments without need to parse again otherwise a shell need to parse the argument again. Try to add `-T` argument to `ssh` to remove the `tty` allocation.

Comment: Keeping ssh and adding -T didn't do it. How do you suggest I send these arguments over ssh?

Comment: It was just a long shot.... IMHO my first comment is the only way to do it :(

Comment: you can try Paramiko to do ssh client http://docs.paramiko.org/en/1.15/api/client.html or some other implementation https://wiki.python.org/moin/SecureShell . By that you can have a fine control of how to call scripts on the remote host

Comment: OK thanks for the help! I'm not sure I can convince other people here to use paramiko. Let's say it is very easy for me to parse the argument. What is the correct call to Popen that I'm looking for? `prog = subprocess.Popen(["ssh", "localhost", '"--act=\'hej hej\' --exit"'])`?

Comment: What about call it by `--act "hej hej"`